# route in google map api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using this URI:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin= ...
```

which works fine. I can hydrate a C# Poco from JSON and access data like this:

```
root.Data.routes[0].legs[0].steps[0].polyline;
```

The raw data looks like this:

```
"agoyHx{Xf@k@z@}@TWp@{@j@g@LQ"
```

What is this and what can I do with this? At the end of the day I would like to draw the route (along streets) on a map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a encoded path, it may be decoded via [`google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#encoding).

See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Encoding

Comment: Thanks I figured this in the meantime. I used this in C#: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/312248/Google-Maps-Direction-API-V-Polyline-Decoder